# Dataverse single choice column showing values instead of the label text on CSV file after export

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I am trying to export data from powerapps gallery to a CSV file on a button click event, but I found out that all the single choice columns are showing values but not the labels, I tried getting the label texts using the code below in create a CSV table, and Select power automate actions :

```
 item()?['wa_city@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue']
```

I am using this code on the Create a CSV table action:

```
 json(triggerBody()['text'])
```

It returns null values for all of them! I would appreciate assistance from anyone.